# Say a customer could enter a bank randomly every 2-6 seconds, what would be the statistical percentage of a person entering each second?

Tags: math, statistics, simulation

I'm writing a bank simulation program and I'm trying to find that percent to know how fast to program a new person coming in based on a timer that executes code every second. Sorry if it sounds kinda confusing, but I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to generate a new person entity every 2-6 seconds, why not generate a random number between 2 and 6, and set the timer to wait that amount of time. When the timer expires, generate the new customer.

However, if you really want the equivalent probability, you can get it by asking what it represents: the stochastic experiment is "at any given second of the clock, what is proability of a client entering, such that it will result in one client every 2-6 seconds?". Pick a specific incidence: say one client every 2 seconds. If on average you get 1 client every 2 seconds, then clearly the probability of getting a client at any given second is 1/2. If on average you get 1 client every 6 seconds, the probability of getting a client at any given second is 1/6.

Comment: @user3461709 Here at Stackoverflow we don't say "Thanks"; we accept and upvote answers instead. If this answer helps you, please consider accepting it. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/157577)

Comment: @Ali I'll remember that next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%5fdistribution) gives the probability of observing *k* independant events in a period for which the average number of events is *λ*

P(*k*) = *λ*<sup>*k*</sup> *e*<sup>-*λ*</sup> / *k*!

This covers the case of more than one customer arriving at the same time.

The easiest way to generate Poisson distributed random numbers is to repeatedly draw from the [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/exponential%5fdistribution), which yields the waiting time for the next event, until the total time exceeds the period.

```
int k = 0;
double t = 0.0;

while(t<period)
{
    t += -log(1.0-rnd())/lambda;
    if(t<period) ++k;
}
```

where `rnd` returns a uniform random number between 0 and (strictly less than) 1, `period` is the number of seconds and `lambda` is the average number of arrivals per second (or, as noted in the previous answer, 1 divided by the average number of seconds between arrivals).

Comment: Even more common in discrete event simulation is to generate one exponential when there is an arrival, and add it to the current time to derive when the next arrival will occur.

Comment: Very interesting, but I don't think that's what the OP is looking for. A Poisson distribution gives the probability of N events in a time interval of interest, given that you know that there are lambda events per interval, on average. For example, 1 customer every 2-6 seconds would mean 10-30 customers (events) per minute. If you then say that your average # customers per minute is 20, then P(X) gives probability of getting X=0, 1, 2, 3, .... , 30, 31, etc customers in a given minute. This is not same as probability of getting a customer during any given second.

Comment: An average of 20 customers per minute is equivalent to 1/3 of a customer per second. If you simply use a probability that _a_ customer arrives in a given second, you'll miss the (admittedly less likely) event of _two or more_ customers arriving in that second.